# Apache .htaccess - what is the meaning of following lines

Tags: apache

From where i can get all knowledge of  apache  .htaccess as a starter

What is the meaning of following lines:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]*)$ index.php?do=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]*)/$ index.php?do=$1 [NC]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout docs atL

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

The commands you have mentioned are part of rewrite engine "a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite requested URLs on the fly".

From docs:
RewriteEngine Directive
Description:    Enables or disables runtime rewriting engine
Syntax: RewriteEngine on|off

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

It means the URLs will be rewritten, ie:

http://yourdomain.com/whatever

will internally be translated into something like:

http://yourdomain.com/index.php?do=whatever